# Does a girl need to provide 4 witness for a rape case?

Tags: sharia, rape

There is a similar question but it's answers are unclear, can someone give a clear answer with references from quran and hadith. Jazakallah

Comment: According to Muhammad's decree in ahadith, four male witnesses are required to accuse only a woman of zina. Four witnesses are not supposed to prove any man's rape. For example, if a husband accuses a wife of zina, he is supposed to bring four male witnesses to substantiate his claim. There is more. In the ahadith, a rape victim was NOT ASKED to bring four male witnesses to accuse a rapist, and yet she received a favourable justice against her rapist.